# Duplicate Tensorflow normal distribution objects

Tags: random, tensorflow, tensorboard, normal-distribution

Given the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

normal_dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(.5, 1.3)
foo = normal_dist.sample()
bar = normal_dist.sample()
baz = foo + bar

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs", graph=tf.get_default_graph())
```

the normal distribution object is duplicated twice for a total of three objects which is bad, because as you can see they are all the same distribution (same mean,std).

Is there a way to not duplicate? Or a way to optimize? Looking for best practices.

[image: three normal distributions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sample()` method creates a *new* tensor, which receives random values from the distribution. Under the hood, `Normal` uses [`tf.random_normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal) op, which itself also creates a new node in graph upon calling.

If don't want to create new ops each time, you can simply evaluate the same random tensor multiple times:

```
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(foo))
  print(sess.run(foo))
  print(sess.run(foo))
```

... this will output a different random value each time.

By the way, note that `Normal_1` and `Normal_2` on the tensorboard picture are not objects, but the *names scopes* that contain the ops to calculate the value (you can expand and zoom in to see that). The bottom `Normal` is also a scope that contains some common tensors for `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. Curious if you can expand the answer to include how to change the name from Normal_1 (and Normal_2) to something I choose? I tried `foo = normal_dist.sample(name="sample_1")` and it does not help.

Comment: `name` argument works for me. Did you clean up the summary logs?

Comment: for me the `sample_1` named scope appears *inside* the `Normal_1` named scope. I'm trying to rename `Normal_1`. Using Tensorflow 1.5 (and Tensorboard 1.5) on Mac. Hmmmm

Comment: Strange indeed. Try to set the name of `tf.contrib.distributions.Normal` as well?